# Merging content of cells with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, format

I'm trying to merge the content of some cells into one, but each piece of information in one line within the cell. Does anyone know how to do it with VBA? I attach a picture to help explain it.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: why?

Comment: I will be inserting them in a macro for StatPlanet Plus, a geography program. The information will be display as it is attached. I have tried other ways but it just looks too messy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code should do the trick:

```
Sub MergeContents()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value = _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value & ": " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & Chr(10) & _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value & ": " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & Chr(10) & _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value & ": " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & Chr(10) & _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Value & ": " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: wow yes it does, I really really appreciate it! You have saved me from A LOT of wasted time trying to format my data base!! ;)